# How can I get an OAuth2 bearer token from the browser?

Tags: c#, selenium, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to get a bearer authentication token from a browser web page.
I'm using selenium and previously I could login to our URL and the bearer token was displayed in a form field. Now it has changed and the token is hidden. How can I extract that token and store into a variable?

This was my previous code (i know it's not great but I am not a developer by any means)..

```
        IWebElement tokenField = getDriver().FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]"));
        string token = tokenField.Text;

        restClient.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(token, "Bearer");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to OAuth2 and just security in general.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you won't be able to find sensitive data like auth token displayed in the FE.
If the token is hidden and you cannot take it from FE or DOM, you can login using API calls and from there to get the token which can be used in the further requests.

If you're working within a development team, you can ask a dev to guide you with this and provide login url and other necessary stuff.